# mp3 files not getting downloaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, mime-types

I have written the below lines of code in c#

```
 private void DownloadFile(byte[] myData, string Name)
    {
        Response.Expires = 0;
        Response.Clear();
        string ext= System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Name);
        switch(ext)
        {
            case ".mp3":
                 Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
                break;
            default:
            Response.ContentType = "Application/octet-stream";
            break;
        }
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", myData.Length.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Name);
        try
        {
            Response.BinaryWrite(myData);
        }
        catch { }
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Now the issue is that whenever we click mp3 file to download, it's directly played. I want that it should download it. Also I want that all types of files should be downloaded.

Comment: Does the MIME type exist in the list of types in your IIS server?

Comment: I dont know how to check it

Comment: @freefaller since the content-type is being set explicitly, would that matter?

Comment: I was starting to wonder that myself @Marc

Comment: @user - as Marc says, it probably won't make any difference when transmitting the file directly from the code - but worth checking just in case.  Have a [look here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for instructions

Comment: the key thing here *should* just be the content-disposition header; have you looked at the actual http headers received to check that your content-disposition header isn't being nuked before it gets to the client? Worst case: just send everything as "application/octet-stream". However, note that some browsers (cough *IE* cough) have a nasty habit of caring about the file extension *in the url*. Note that the name in `filename="{name}"` component should *technically* be *quoted* (rfc2616 section 19), but should be OK either way

Comment: Are there any methods or not

Comment: Ah, sorry - I've just re-read the question, and if the MP3 is *playing* then obviously the file is getting to the browser.  My guess would be a lack of quotes on a filename with spaces

Comment: @user2179026 methods of...?

Comment: @freefaller indeed; I would be **very** interested in seeing the *actual received* http headers (just content-type and content-disposition) for a http request that is misbehaving; user217902: can you please capture and show the actual received headers?

Comment: @Marc, looks like the OP was looking for the silver bullet - they just wanted us to tell them the answer, rather than do anything to investigate it themselves.  Fortunately there are plenty of people who appreciate the army of **volunteers** on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this for the longest time, but finally solved the puzzle. Use Response.WriteFile. You could follow it with Response.Flush but I found that to be unnecessary.  Extra headers were not necessary with .mp3 files. In my case, the .mp3 files were in a folder directly under the root. And here's a bonus: The key ingredients for making the .mp3 download work with smartphones (which was my dilemma) were using Response.End, and telling the mobile device that the download was done by sending back the Response.StatusCode = 200.

```
string FilenameMP3 = "~/someFolder/xyz.mp3";
string headerFilename = Filename.Substring(Filename.IndexOf("/") + 1);
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Concat("attachment;filename=\"", headerFilename, "\""));
Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
try
{
    Response.WriteFile(Filename, true);
    Response.End();
}
finally
{
     Response.StatusCode = 200;
     Response.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have *should* be sufficient, assuming that the headers you added aren't being stripped / corrupted in transit (simple to check via Fiddler or similar).

Since you don't want the browser to interpret this data, a pragmatic option might be to simply send all data as "application/octet-stream", regardless of the content. While the "attachment" disposition should be sufficient for this, this approach is explicitly called out in RFC 2616, 19.5.1 ("Content-Disposition"):

> If this header is used in a response with the application/octet- stream content-type, the implied suggestion is that the user agent should not display the response, but directly enter a `save response as...' dialog.